# How to get start and end week date using week number in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date, count, query-optimization, date-arithmetic

I can easily get the start date and end of week like below.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS reports_in_week,
    DATE_ADD(mydate, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(mydate)) DAY),
    DATE_ADD(mydate, INTERVAL(7-DAYOFWEEK(mydate)) DAY)
FROM mytable
where WEEK(mydate,1) = '29'
GROUP BY WEEK(mydate,1)
```

but the problem is that case indexing of column date is not working, if i pass date range between indexing will work, i try to get the start date and end date of week using week number;

I am starter in mysql please help.

Comment: What does ___case indexing of column date___ mean. Does that just mean you need to add an `ORDER BY` clause to get the reault you want?

Comment: i need to do some aggregate like sum on some column by date

Comment: @RiggsFolly ; i can get the start date and end using index number than i can change by where clause like where date between start_date and end_date; as i have only week number

Comment: @Dev I think this question would benefit greatly from some sample data and an example what the desired output would look

Comment: For "why" see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to filter on a given week *and year*, then one option is to use `str_to_date()` to generate a date range from a year and week number:

```
where 
        mydate >= str_to_date('2020-29 Monday', '%Y-%u %W')
    and mydate <  str_to_date('2020-29 Monday', '%Y-%u %W') + interval 7 day
```

The `%u` specifier represents a week number, with Monday being the first day of the week (so this is like `WEEK()` in mode `1`, which your query uses).

The above `where` predicate would take advantage of an index on `mydate` - which seems to be your purpose here.

Comment: second condition should be <=

Comment: @Dev: actually it should be `<` (since it's 8 days later). Fixed.